# Difference between d3.event.x and d3.mouse(this)

Tags: d3.js

I know that `d3.mouse(this)` is used to get the mouse coordinates.

Example:

```
var coordinates = [0, 0];
coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
var x = coordinates[0];
var y = coordinates[1];
```

but what is `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y` used for? I went through the docs which lookslike greek and latin to me

Can any one please explain differences as well? Thanks